# Property binding to function

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind the background-color of an element to a function:

```
 <td [style.background-color]="patientService.getSeverityColor(interval.averageSeverity)">{{interval.earliestTime}}-{{interval.latestTime}}</td>
```

This used to work, but it doesn't anymore and I'm not why. Am i even supposed to bind properties to functions, or should I only do it with component properties?

The reason I'm doing this is that interval.averageSeverity is a number that represents a certain color, so I'm passing the number to the function and it returns the color:

```
getSeverityColor(severity: number) {
switch (severity) {
  case -1:
    return "grey";
  case 0:
    return "green";

  case 1:
    return "yellow";

  case 2:
    return "orange";

  case 3:
    return "red";

}
}
```

If i can't bind to a function, do you have any suggestions as to how I could solve this? Thanks.

EDIT, more code:

```
<div class="patients-container" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (drop)="onDrop($event)">
  <div class="patient-box level-1" draggable="true" *ngFor="let bed of beds" (dragstart)="onDrag($event, bed)">
    <div class="location-header">
      <p class="location" (click)="openEditPatientDialog(bed)">{{bed.philipsName}}<md-icon>edit</md-icon></p>
      <p class="name" [hidden]="bed.patientName == ''">{{bed.patientName}}</p>
      <p class="O2" [hidden]="!additionalO2"><img  (click)="toggleO2()" src="../../assets/med_O2.png"></p>
      <p class="O2" [hidden]="additionalO2"><img  (click)="toggleO2()" src="../../assets/no_O2.png"></p>
      <p class="triage"><md-icon [style.color]="patientService.getSeverityColor(bed.absoluteSeverity)">favorite</md-icon></p>
    </div>
    <div class="intervals-header"> 
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let interval of bed.timeWindows">
          <td [ngStyle]="{'background-color': patientService.getSeverityColor(interval.averageSeverity)}">{{interval.earliestTime}}-{{interval.latestTime}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the default value for `interval.averageSeverity`? Or is there one?

Comment: @amal There is no default value

Comment: okay, isn't it working? If there is no default value, then you need to have a default case as well for the switch inside your called method. See my second recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#how-to-use).

```
<td [ngStyle]="{'background-color': patientService.getSeverityColor(interval.averageSeverity)}">{{interval.earliestTime}}-{{interval.latestTime}}</td>
```

You might have to likely specify a default `number` (or return a default color string value within the method) so that the method returns a valid color string by default.

For example if you want to return `'grey'` by default, add this to your method,

```
getSeverityColor(severity: number) {
 switch (severity) {
  case -1:
    return "grey";
  case 0:
    return "green";

  case 1:
    return "yellow";

  case 2:
    return "orange";

  case 3:
    return "red";

  default:
    return "grey";

 }
}
```

Comment: I tried setting the default color to blue which works, but I've been testing with an object that has -1, so it should be returning grey. I think I have a stupid mistake somewhere but I can't spot it.

Comment: I've added more code - I don't think there's more relevant. As you can see I'm using the getSeverityColor() method elsewhere too and that one is working fine.

Comment: Could you show your `bed.timeWindows` array elements as well?

Comment: Turns out our backend has changed so it doesn't return -1 anymore but values like 6, which isn't covered in the switch! Not sure why I didn't think about checking that. Anyway, thanks for your help. Btw, can you tell me why  getSeverityColor() gets called so many times? I tried to add a console.log() to it, and my console is getting spammed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Because it is being part of a dynamic property binding in the template and thus being continuously evaluated for changes.